Find the segment "DC" in the obtuse triangle below
In an obtuse triangle $ABC$, obtuse at $B$, the internal bisector $AD$ is drawn and in $AC$ the point $"q"$ is taken such that $m∡⁢⁢=90^$.
Calculate $DC$. If: $AQ = 10$ and $AB = BC$.
$Answer:10$

I try
$\angle QAD= \theta = \angle DAB$
$\frac{AB}{BD} = \frac{10+CQ}{CD}$
$\triangle ABC_{(isosc.)}\implies \angle C = 2\theta$
$\therefore \angle A = 180^o -4\theta$
$ \angle BDA = 3\theta \implies \angle QDC = 90-3\theta$
$ \angle CDQ  = 90+\theta$

There are a few typos. It's $\angle B$, not $\angle A$, which is $180^{\circ} - 4\theta$. Also, it's $\angle CQD$, not $\angle CDQ$, that's $90^{\circ}+\theta$. In addition, as my answer indicates, the value of $\lvert DC\rvert$ is one-half that of $\lvert AQ\rvert$, not equal as your question states. Please check to see if there's also a typo with one of those stated values.


Let $\angle BAD = \angle CAD = \alpha$ then $\angle BAD =\angle BCA = 2\alpha$
Draw $DE$ such that $AE=QE$ ($E$ is the midpoint of $AQ$)
then $AE=QE=DE=5$ and $\angle ADE = \angle DAE = \alpha$
then $\angle DEC =2\alpha$ (exterior $\angle$ of $\triangle ADE$)
then $\angle DEC = \angle DCE = 2\alpha$
$DC=DE=5$ (sides are $=$ opposite $= \angle$'s)

Thanks for help

Let $R$ be the midpoint of $AQ$, so $\lvert AR\rvert = \lvert RQ\rvert = 5$. Since $\triangle ADQ$ is right-angled, then $AQ$ is the diameter of its circumcircle, so $R$ is its center, which means that $\lvert DR\rvert = \frac{10}{2} = 5$.
Since $\triangle ARD$ is isosceles, then $\measuredangle ADR = \theta$, so $\measuredangle RDQ = \theta$ also. Using that $\measuredangle BDA = 3\theta$, we get
$$\measuredangle RDC = 180^{\circ} - 3\theta - \theta = 180^{\circ} - 4\theta$$
With $\measuredangle DCR = 2\theta$, this means
$$\measuredangle DRC = 180^{\circ} - (180^{\circ} - 4\theta) - 2\theta = 2\theta$$
This shows $\triangle RDC$ is also isoscles, so
$$\lvert DC \rvert = \lvert DR \rvert = 5$$
which matches the result, where the law of sines was used instead, of my other answer.

Using your result of $\measuredangle CQD = 90^{\circ} + \theta$ and the Law of sines with $\triangle CDQ$ gives
$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\frac{\lvert DC\rvert}{\sin(90^{\circ} + \theta)} & = \frac{\lvert DQ\rvert}{\sin(2\theta)} \\
\frac{\lvert DC\rvert}{\cos\theta} & = \frac{\lvert DQ\rvert}{2\sin\theta\cos\theta} \\
\lvert DC\rvert & = \frac{\lvert DQ\rvert}{2\sin\theta}
\end{aligned}\end{equation}$$
From $\triangle ADQ$, we get
$$\sin\theta = \frac{\lvert DQ\rvert}{\lvert AQ\rvert} \;\;\to\;\; \lvert DQ\rvert = 10\sin\theta$$
Substituting this into the earlier equation results in
$$\lvert DC\rvert = \frac{10\sin\theta}{2\sin\theta} = 5$$
However, this doesn't match your stated answer. In general, $\lvert DC\rvert$ is half that of $\lvert AQ\rvert$, as your diagram also roughly  indicates.
